# Get Method for LINQ-TO-SQL object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'd like to add a new constructor to one of my LTS objects inside a partial class. It should return an instance of the object from the database. Basically the idea is

```
public Questionnaire(int id)
{
    this = (from q in db.Questionnaires
            where q.Id == id
            select q).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I can go through each property and set it to that of the returned object but that seems like overkill and if I change my database model I will have to ensure I edit this code.

So what's the best practice for doing this? I can't go for a static method because the DataContext will not be able to track any changes I make to the object.

**Would I have to create a new instance of the class, then call a GET method on that class? i.e.**

```
public Questionnaire Get(int id)
{
    return (from q in db.Questionnaires
            where q.Id == id
            select q).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

**Then use it**

```
Questionnaire qs = new Questionnaire();
qs = qs.Get(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to follow the implementation suggested by Mike Hadlow in his blog [post](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.pt/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html).

Basically what you'll be doing is implement that retrieval logic (and other operations) in a class that acts as the repository for a specific kind of objects (in your case - Questionnaire).

It will be something like the following

```
var rep = new Repository<Questionnaire>(...);

var questionnaire = rep.GetById(1);
```

Comment: That's quite a good concept and an alternative solution to my problem. Would like to see if what I'm trying to achieve is possible though.

Comment: From my point of view, you should avoid the first solution since you're creating a new object inside a constructor and assigning it to the the variable that holds the object you're creating. It's weird.

As for the second one, it is valid, buy your trying to encapsulate logic into your domain object. This logic should belong in some kind of repository (hence the name of the pattern) for your data.

Comment: The first option I posted is only there to try and explain what I'm wanting to achieve. I understand that I shouldn't have to mix logic and the domain object however each individual class will need to have their own methods for accessing data. A Get(), GetAll(), Insert() will obviously not be enough. I have methods such as GetAllForClient(...), GetAllForUser(...) under the Questionnaire class, then the User object would have GetAllByClient(), GetCurrentUser() etc. Where would I place these methods if I was to use the Repository pattern?

Comment: You would have the methods GetAllForClient(...), GetAllForUser(...) in the Repository<Questionnaire> class. 

In this case to make it generic you should write a method like GetAllForType<T>(...) where T would be Client, User or any other class. The logic for the method would be to access the property that represents the key for type T, which would lead you to define a base class/interface for all your domain objects to implement. This interface would force all your domain objects to expose a Key property that you would use to make this kind of joins.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to your approach is to use a wrapper class with a constructor that retrieves the Questionnaire instance from DB. I hate such an approach (a [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) would be preferred, exactly like the above mentioned repository).

```
public class QuestionnaireWrapper: Questionnaire {

    private Questionnaire _q;

    public QuestionnaireWrapper(int id)
    {
        _q = (from q in db.Questionnaires
            where q.Id == id
            select q).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public new string Name 
    {
        get { return _q.Name; }
        set { _q.Name = value; }
    }

    [Other overrides, all of them]
}
```

What you tried to achieve (`this = ...`) is **not** possible because violates basic programming principles. I used such an approach only once, when I needed to create remotable wrappers (`: MarshalByRefObject`) for objects that were not remotable. And believe me, that is not a clean approach. Please don't downvote me for bad code when I clearly say that ;-)

Observation no. 2: by reading the second part of your code I found you were close. That's why static methods are for!! :)

```
public static Questionnaire Get(int id)
{
    return (from q in db.Questionnaires
            where q.Id == id
            select q).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

then

```
Questionnaire qs = Questionnaire.Get(1);
```

Comment: While I concour with you, since in this case the Repository pattern may be a little bit overkill, he said that he couldn't use static methods "because the DataContext will not be able to track any changes I make to the object". I still think that this would be the preferable approach, but it seems it can't be done.